# mysql join query with like?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-like

Here is a representation of my db structure with a couple example rows. What I am attempting to accomplish is to take the address from table 1 and search in table 2 for a like match. Then I just need it to return the sub column result

```
    Table 1
    id | address        | info
    ----------------------------------------
    1  | 123 test dr    | blah blah blah
    2  | 456 testing ln | blah blah blah blah

    Table 2
    id | wo        | addr           | sec    | sub
    ------------------------------------------------
    1  | 12345678  | 123 TEST DR    | Sec. 1 | Sub1
    2  | 87654321  | 456 TESTING LN | Sec. 2 | Sub2
```

I have tried some join queries however I just can't seem to get it to work

Comment: "sub column result"? Huh? you can use any kind of condition to join on, e.g. `join foo on bar.x like foo.y`

Comment: Can you post the queries you tried?

Comment: tablescan heaven here

Comment: Why do you need to use `LIKE`? It looks like the addresses in the two tables match exactly (except for differences in case, which MySQL normally ignores).

Comment: from the sample of data you gave- are you sure like command is what you need? it looks to me that `UPPER()` is what you need here to join the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use something like:

```
select t2.sub 
from   Table1 t1
       left join Table2 t2 on t2.add like CONCAT('%', t1.address,'%')
```

Comment: Joining on a condition with a leading wildcard will be all sorts of inefficient...

Answer (score 0):

that is not very best idea, but just as learning proccess of mysql options you can take a look on my approach:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4962/2

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.address LIKE CONCAT('%',t2.addr,'%');
```